# Return Promise Value from Page Object using TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, selenium, typescript, webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to return a value from a WebDriver promise within a Protractor solution using TypeScript, but I'm getting `undefined` as response.

```
get nameInput(): string {
    var value: string;
    this.nameElement.getAttribute('value').then(v => value = v);
    return value;
}
```

In the above case it seems like the function is not waiting for the promise to return, therefore I tried moving away from the getter style and declared the return type as WebDriver's promise:

```
getNameInput(): webdriver.promise.Promise<string> {

    var nameElement = element(by.id('name'));
    return nameElement.getText().then(v => { return v });

}
```

But I'm getting `Function` as the return instead of the value of `v`. Seems like the promise is not being unwrapped by Jasmine's `expect`, as it happens when running it in JS.

I know I can run the promise directly within the expect, but ideally I would create all the function's logic outside of any expectations, so that I can then feed the expectation the function call with any (if any) parameters only - instead of polluting the test case with promise logic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to resolve the promises, just *return them*:

```
getNameInput(): webdriver.promise.Promise<string> {
    var nameElement = element(by.id('name'));
    return nameElement.getText();
}
```

Then you need to have a real value returned from the `getNameInput()` - resolve it in your test:

```
getNameInput().then(v => { console.log(v) });
```

Note that, you also let `expect()` resolve it implicitly:

```
expect(getNameInput()).toEqual("Expected Value");
```